# How does scss style inheritance and React work?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

So im building a small React application to test theming. I've always used css variables but after watching a tutorial on sass i realized it has potential to do easy theming and to prove my point there are many tutorials online.
But im having a problem. I generally have my projects in a structure where every component has a css file like:

```
- src
    - components
         - Home
             - Home.tsx
             - Home.module.scss
```

Now this is my code:

```
_themes.scss
$themes: (
  light: (
    bg-color: #c0c0c0, ...
  ),
  dark: (
    bg-color: #37474f, ....
  ),
);

// mixins.scss
@use "sass:map";
@import "./themes";

@mixin themed($key, $color) {
  @each $theme-name, $theme-color in $themes {
    .theme-#{$theme-name} & {
      #{$key}: map.get(map.get($themes, $theme-name), $color);
    }
  }
}

// index.scss
@import "./styles/mixins";

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Readex Pro", sans-serif;
  @include themed("background-color", "bg-color");
}

code {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
}

// App.tsx
export default function App() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const session = useSelector(sessionSelector)
    const theme = useSelector(themeSelector)

    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.className = '';
        document.documentElement.classList.add(`theme-${theme.name}`)
    }, [theme])

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
                <Route path={paths.home} element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="protect" element={<RequireAuth roles={['test']} />}>

                </Route>
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

In index.tsx i import index.scss and my body is getting style as well as changing when i change the theme to dark, the color changes.
My problem is: when i am in another component the scss works but without applying the themes. As i show previously i change the theme in my app and it does change.

Yet when I am in my header component, who's top div has this .wrapper class in the className, none of the themed stuff shows as I show in the image.
Any ideias?

PS: i probably should mention im very new to sass and don't really understand very advanced stuff just yet.

```
@import "../../styles/mixins";

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: red;
  @include themed("background", "header-color");
}
```

[image]

Everything I apply in the index.scss file it works, any other sass module it doesnt. But only the theme mixin, all others i have work

Comment: If I understand your code, you apply the theme styles to the class `.wrapper`, but your component has the class `Header_wrapper__XIx1Y` on the screenshot. How could it work?

Comment: Its css/sass modules. that's how it works

Comment: So you're importing this class on the `Header` component? You didn't share all of your code so I was not sure.

Comment: I think it's just a typo, the first parameter you send to the mixin, `"header-color"`, is not a valid css property.

Comment: I did say i was using it on Header, and as it are modules, it renames the class to Header_wrapper something

Comment: I saw that and forgot to update the question. However it still wont work, Tried backgound, and background-color and yet the mixin doesnt produce anything